# OpenCV Image Sharpening（Can't find the MISTAKE in my code）

Tags: opencv

```
void sharpen(IplImage *in,IplImage *out)
{
    int r=in->height;
    int c=in->width;
    int st=in->widthStep;
    int i,j;
    for(i=1;i<r-1;i++)
    {
        uchar *cur=(uchar *)(in->imageData+i*st);
        uchar *pre=(uchar *)(in->imageData+(i-1)*st);
        uchar *next=(uchar *)(in->imageData+(i+1)*st);
        uchar *output=(uchar *)(out->imageData+i*st);
        for(j=3;j<c*3-3;j++)
        {
            *output=uchar(5*cur[j]-cur[j-3]-cur[j+3]-pre[j]-next[j]);
            *output++;
        }
    }

}
```

OpenCV Image sharpening using Laplacian...
Would you mind finding out mistakes for me?

Comment: What are the expected results and what result are you getting ?

Answer (score 0):

One obvious mistake is that:

```
        *output++;
```

should be:

```
        output++;
```

i.e. you just need to increment the pointer, not dereference it. But I don't think that's your only bug.